# How can I add a small logo which is always hovering on every product in grid in woocommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-theming

I very new to Woocommerce and Wordpress, I am trying to add a different company logo to each different products in grid but I am not able to do it, I have also tried to find any plugin related to it but I found nothing. Please Friends if you know how to do it do let me Know.

There is the below image of what I am trying to get but not able to :

[Click Here for Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N76Yj.png)

Comment: do you want on product single page or on shop list product page

Comment: On Product shop List Page

Comment: First download the acf plugin then make the image field for wooCommerce product only , After made the image field for products, Try  " woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title " hook in function.php file ,where you can echo the image field of acf by "get_field" function for ACF. "here is the link : ---- https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/"

Answer (score 0):

First download the acf plugin then make the image field for wooCommerce product only , After made the image field for products, Try  " woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title " hook in function.php file ,where you can echo the image field of acf by "get_field" function for ACF. "here is the link : ---- https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/".

```
        <?php 
    // define the woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title callback 
       function action_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title(  ) { 
    // make action magic happen here... 
        $image = get_field('image'); // ACF field name/slug.
            if( !empty($image) ){
        ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />
        <?php
            }

            }; 

    // add the action 
        add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'action_woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 10, 0 ); 
    ?>
```

This will show the image on products ,After that do some styling on that in your theme style.css

If above hook does not work try this hook "woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item",